# How do I avoid a Duplicate-value during update in Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, error-messages, after-trigger, duplicate-value

I'm changing the `Clients__c` value in `Mopping__c` if the `StartDate__c`, `Status__c` or `Opportunity__c` have changed in the needed `Rent__c`.

Structure: if **Mopping 1** is related to **Rent 1** which is related to **Opportunity 1**, and `EndDate__c` of the **Mopping 1** == `StartDate__c` of **Rent 2** which is too related to **Opportunity 1**, `Clients__c` of **Mopping 1** should be equals to `Clients__c` of **Rent 2**:

[image]

But! If `StartDate__c` of **Rent 2** is changed and != to `EndDate__c` of the **Mopping 1**, `Clients__c` of **Mopping 1** should be `null` again. The same thing with changing `Status__c` of **Rent 2** to 'Canceled' and it's `Opportunity__c`.

We have to check the old Mopping-neighbors of moved Rent and also new Mopping-neighbors. That's why I'm checking `Trigger.old` and `Trigger.new` in the one List. If our `Mopping__c` haven't already needed `Rent__c` which meets the conditions `mop.EndDate__c == rent.StartDate__c && mop.Rent__r.Opportunity__c == rent.Opportunity__c && rent.Status__c != 'Canceled'`, the `mop.Clients__c` field should be `null`. But if `Rent__c` that matches the conditions appears, the `mop.Clients__c` changes again. Schema:

[image]

**The problem 1:** there can be 2 or more `Rents` with `mop.EndDate__c == rent.StartDate__c && mop.Rent__r.Opportunity__c == rent.Opportunity__c`, but only one of them will be witn `rent.Status__c != 'Canceled'`. And they can be updated in the same time. So when I'm trying to added in my list 2 same `Moppongs` for `Rents`, that meet different conditions, I'm getting Duplicate error and can't update my List.

**The problem 2:** I have here the loop in the loop. So I'm also getting `Too many SOQL queries: 101` when inserting or updating many `Rents`.

Trigger:

```
trigger ClientsTrigger on Rent__c (after insert, after update) {
    List<Rent__c> allRents = new List<Rent__c>();
    TriggerHelper helper = new TriggerHelper();

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) {
        allRents.addAll(Trigger.new);
        helper.updatingHelper(allRents);
    }
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {
        allRents.addAll(Trigger.new);
        allRents.addAll(Trigger.old);
        helper.updatingHelper(allRents);
    }
}
```

Helper:

```
public void updatingHelper(List<Rent__c> allRents){
    List<Mopping__c> moppingsToUpdate = new List<Mopping__c>();
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(Rent__c rent : allRents){
        oppIds.add(rent.Opportunity__c);
    }
    Map<Id, Opportunity> rentsMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(
        [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Clients__c, StartDate__c, Opportunity__c, Status__c FROM Rents__r WHERE EndDate__c >=: Date.TODAY())
         FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : oppIds AND Name != 'Test']
    );
    List<Mopping__c> actualMoppings = [SELECT Id, Clients__c, EndDate__c, Rent__r.Opportunity__c FROM Mopping__c
                                       WHERE Rent__r.Opportunity__c IN : oppIds AND EndDate__c >=: Date.TODAY()];
    for(Mopping__c actualMopping: actualMoppings){
        List<Rent__c> neededRents = rentsMap.get(actualMopping.Rent__r.Opportunity__c).Rents__r;
        List<Date> listDate = new List<Date>();

        //Loop in loop is bad because of "Too many SOQL queries: 101":
        for(Rent__c neededRent: neededRents){
            listDate.add(neededRent.StartDate__c);
            if(actualMopping.EndDate__c == neededRent.StartDate__c && actualMopping.Clients__c != String.valueOf(neededRent.Clients__c) && neededRent.Status__c != 'Canceled'){
                actualMopping.Clients__c = String.valueOf(neededRent.Clients__c);
                moppingsToUpdate.add(actualMopping);
            } else if(actualMopping.EndDate__c == neededRent.StartDate__c && neededRent.Status__c == 'Canceled' && !moppingsToUpdate.contains(actualMopping)){      
                actualMopping.Clients__c = '';
                //Sometimes one Rent__c can become 'Canceled' and another Rent__c with the same EndDate__c and Opportunity
                //can be not 'Canceled'. Then we get the same Mopping in our List:
                moppingsToUpdate.add(actualMopping);
            }
        }
        if(!listDate.contains(actualMopping.EndDate__c)){
            actualMopping.Clients__c = '';
            moppingsToUpdate.add(actualMopping);
        }
        listDate.clear();
    }
    if(!moppingsToUpdate.isEmpty()){
        //Error with Duplicates in List (with Set I have the same problem):
        update moppingsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to set up a [singletone](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Design_Patterns_-_Singleton) pattern for your helper class. You need to make sure that every instance of the helper class is independent. This will help you to reduce governor limits.

You are passing all Rents records that are changing. I think you should use here a logic to pass only those Rents that have changes on the fields that have an effect on you logic, `StartDate__c` and `Status__c`. This way you reduce the amount of records for further processing. Because you are passing all Opportunities. You can pass the oldMap to your helper class?

```
for(Rent__c rent : allRents){
    oppIds.add(rent.Opportunity__c);
}
```

You should not use for loops inside for loops:

```
for(Mopping__c actualMopping: actualMoppings){
    List<Rent__c> neededRents = rentsMap.get(actualMopping.Rent__r.Opportunity__c).Rents__r;
    List<Date> listDate = new List<Date>();

    //Loop in loop is bad because of "Too many SOQL queries: 101":
    for(Rent__c neededRent: neededRents){
        listDate.add(neededRent.StartDate__c);
        if(actualMopping.EndDate__c == neededRent.StartDate__c && actualMopping.Clients__c != String.valueOf(neededRent.Clients__c) && neededRent.Status__c != 'Canceled'){
            actualMopping.Clients__c = String.valueOf(neededRent.Clients__c);
            moppingsToUpdate.add(actualMopping);
        } else if(actualMopping.EndDate__c == neededRent.StartDate__c && neededRent.Status__c == 'Canceled' && !moppingsToUpdate.contains(actualMopping)){      
            actualMopping.Clients__c = '';
            //Sometimes one Rent__c can become 'Canceled' and another Rent__c with the same EndDate__c and Opportunity
            //can be not 'Canceled'. Then we get the same Mopping in our List:
            moppingsToUpdate.add(actualMopping);
        }
    }
```

Try to get the `List<Rent__c> neededRents` out of the for loop.

You can do something like this:

```
List<Rent__c> neededRents = new List<Rent__c>();
for(Mopping__c actualMopping: actualMoppings){
neededRents.add(rentsMap.get(actualMopping.Rent__r.Opportunity__c).Rents__r);
}
```

I think that you can also move the `List<Date> listDate = new List<Date>();` out of the first loop.

**UPDATE:**

I see that you are only using the `listDate` for a final check.

```
if(!listDate.contains(actualMopping.EndDate__c)){
        actualMopping.Clients__c = '';
        moppingsToUpdate.add(actualMopping);
    }
```

The list contains the `neededRent` which it is the same record than the ones on the `neededRents`, correct?.

So you can get the `listDate` out the first loop.

```
List<Rent__c> neededRents = new List<Rent__c>();
List<Date> listDate = new List<Date>();
for(Mopping__c actualMopping: actualMoppings) {    
    neededRents.add(rentsMap.get(
    actualMopping.Rent__r.Opportunity__c).Rents__r);
    listDate.add(neededRent.StartDate__c);
  }
```

I think that you should separate your logic on the tigger and have one method for updating records and one for inserting. I think that you can explore using **before insert** and **before update** as well.

For the trigger (on updates) , and as I mentioned before, you can sent those Rent records that are changing the fields you need to check to avoid operating over to many Opportunities on your process.

```
trigger ClientsTrigger on Rent__c (after update, after insert) {
// Add a list only for update
List<Rent__c> allRentsUpdate = new List<Rent__c>();
List<Rent__c> allRentsInsert = new List<Rent__c>();

TriggerHelper helper = new TriggerHelper();

if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) {
    // Here will come the logic only for insert...
    // you can include a method only for insert
    // helper.insertHelper(allRentsInsert);  
}

if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {
    for(Rent__c rent : Trigger.new) {
        // You can add more logic here
        if(Trigger.oldMap.get(rent.Id).StartDate__c != rent.StartDate__c) {
        allRentsUpdate.add(rent);
        }
    }

    helper.updatingHelper(allRentsUpdate);
  }
}
```

This way you pass to your helper the Rent records you want to execute.

For the second for loop you can try something like this, I didn't test this because I don't have your objects but this is a way to iterate over child records:

```
for(Rent__c neededRent: neededRents){
  for(Mopping__c actualMopping : neededRent.Mopping__r) {
        if(actualMopping.EndDate__c == neededRent.StartDate__c && actualMopping.Clients__c != String.valueOf(neededRent.Clients__c) && neededRent.Status__c != 'Canceled'){
            actualMopping.Clients__c = String.valueOf(neededRent.Clients__c);
            moppingsToUpdate.add(actualMopping);
        } else if(actualMopping.EndDate__c == neededRent.StartDate__c && neededRent.Status__c == 'Canceled' && !moppingsToUpdate.contains(actualMopping)){      
            actualMopping.Clients__c = '';
            moppingsToUpdate.add(actualMopping);
            }
        }
    }
```

This type of for loop is fine because you are iterating from the parent to the child on a relationship.

Can you post the TriggerHander as well?.. This will help us to let you know how to build a singletone for this scenario. It is really smart to use this pattern when possible, it will make a great difference on the overall governor limits when sharing classes.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. There are important changes not only with `Status__c` and `StartDate__c`. As I said already, Rents can jump between Opportunities too, and that's make my task really crazy. And I still didn't get how can I move the `List<Rent__c> neededRents` out of the first loop. I still need to compare values from `neededRents` and `actualMoppings`.

Comment: Check the updates on the first answer.